# Different structs with the same variable names

Tags: c++, c

I have two different structures that have a variable name in common. How can I assign a value with out causing a segmentation fault?

```
struct observer *obs;
obs->next = NULL;

struct sightings *sights;
sights->next = NULL;
```

The code above causes a segmentation fault. Can this be avoided?

Thanks

Comment: you should alloc memory for the each struct.use the malloc d this

Comment: nothing to do with the names of the fields. (try changing to next1 and next2 you will see it fail the same)

Comment: obs and sights are not actually pointed to anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using C:

```
struct observer* obs = malloc(sizeof(*obs));
struct sightings* sights = malloc(sizeof(*sights));
```

If you are using C++:

```
observer* obs = new observer();
sightings* sights = new sightings();
```

Don't forget to `free` or `delete`, respectively, the pointers when you are done with them.

Comment: In C++ this would be considered poor style; `new`'d memory should always be managed by a container.

Answer (score 6):

You're getting a segfault because you never assign a valid value to those pointers. It has nothing to do with the field name `next` shared between them.

[Updated to add, in response to comment:]

If you want to have a dummy element for a list that you don't allocate via `malloc` (or the like), then you can do something like:

```
struct observer dummyHead = { .next = NULL };
struct observer *obs = &dummyHead;
```

Comment: Its because these pointers are to be used to point to the beginning of a linked list. They act like dummy pointers.

Comment: As pointers, they still need to point to *something* in order to be valid.

Comment: note: the question is tagged both C and C++. The designated initializer syntax is only valid in C; however `= { 0 };` would work in both languages. (and zero-initializes all members)

Comment: True enough. I am much more of a C than a C++ programmer.